# How to override equals for a key in a Hibernate map?

Tags: hibernate, orm, dictionary, overriding, equals

I want to override equals to be based on the business key instead of the object identity, but i cannot make it work with hibernate.

I know that similar questions has been asked and reading the answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)) helps understanding not breaking *equivalence relation*, use instanceof instead of getClass, use getters instead of field refs. etc., but my implementation of equals/hashCode still breaks hibernates population of the map.

I do not get an error, hibernate saves all 3 entities in a map correctly in the database, but it only reads 1 instead of all 3 when I read the entity with the map again. The sql logged by hibernate selects all 3 entities correct when it is executed in mysql.

The project is based on Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 4.1.5 and JPA annotations

#### Update

When debugging hibernate it seems to call hashCode for each of the 3 map entities, but all values are null except the hibernate generated id. The hashCode calculated by the overridden method is therefore always the same. I guess that is why only one entity is added to the map. But i don't understand why hibernate calculates the hashCode before loading data from the database?

#### Example

In the example below I have reproduced the error in a project with 3 simple entities (all with hibernate generated ids):

- Item
- Language
- LanguageDetails

Item has a Map of LanguageDetails where Language is the key:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="item", orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKey(name="language")
private Map<Language, LanguageDetails> languageDetails = new TreeMap<Language, LanguageDetails>();
```

The business key in Language is a String called *code*. My best guess of overriding equals has been to generate equals/hashCode using eclipse (and replace getClass with instanceof and field refs. with getters):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getCode() == null) ? 0 : getCode().hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Language))
        return false;
    Language other = (Language) obj;
    if (getCode() == null) {
        if (other.getCode() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!getCode().equals(other.getCode()))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The following integration test fails with the above equals/hashCode and succeeds without:

```
Item item = new Item();
Language english = languageService.getByCode("en");
Language german = languageService.getByCode("de");
Language spanish = languageService.getByCode("es");

item.getLanguageDetails().put(english, new LanguageDetails(item, english, "ice cream"););
item.getLanguageDetails().put(spanish, new LanguageDetails(item, spanish, "helado"););
item.getLanguageDetails().put(german, new LanguageDetails(item, german, "eis"););

//save - stores all 3 languageDetails correct in mysql
int id = itemService.create(item); 

//read - loads only 1 languageDetails (de)
Item readItem = itemService.getById(id); 

//java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<1>
Assert.assertEquals(item.getLanguageDetails().size(), readItem.getLanguageDetails().size());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent almost a week on debugging, writing workarounds and trying to understand this issue and in my increasingly desperate trial and error attempts i found the solution:

I changed my hibernate version from 4.1.5 to 4.1.8 and all my agony went away. It was a bug in hibernate that was fixed in version [4.1.7](https://hibernate.onjira.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10031&version=12250)...

I will certainly check the bug reports earlier next time...